# acknowledgment.nack() feature equivalent in Spring Boot 2.1.8

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Hi I am using `@kafkaListener` from `Spring Boot`. I am consuming batch of messages. I am trying to use `nack()` method from `Acknowledgment` but looks like `Spring Boot 2.1.8` does not support `nack()` method.

Is there any feature like `nack()` in `Spring Boot 2.1.8`

I want to throw an exception for an failure record and replay remaining records in next `poll()`. How can I achieve this in `Spring Boot 2.1.8`. Can I use `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler`? How?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 2.1.x has been end of life for nearly a year; `nack()` was introduced in spring-kafka 2.3.x (comes with Boot 2.2.x, which is also end-of-life). The last 2.1.x release was 2.1.18.

See github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Supported-Versions

As you can see, Boot 2.3.x goes end of life soon, too.

There is no equivalent of `nack()` in earlier versions. See the project page for a matrix of spring-kafka/spring-boot versions.

spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#overview

Yes, you can provide similar functionality with the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` but you should really upgrade to a supported release.